# How to fix infinite bootloop problem in rooted karbonn Sparkle V

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, boot-loop, boot, bootloader, karbonn

I have **Karbonn Sparkle V** and it has **marshmallow** before I root it.

when I root my phone using **Android One toolkit**, its restart my phone after showing message `rooting completed`.

But when it restarts phone stuck on boot display and after that, I try to recover my phone via recovery mode nevertheless problem persists.

Someone plz help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Simplt Flash it with a new stock rom
firstly if you can access adb then backup your data..i dont think you have access to adb..but if by any chance the you can use 
ADB Command:-

"`adb pull /storage/sdcard0/ C:\folderyoumade`"

Download your stock rom from here:-

http://www.mediafire.com/file/uqdnsantv1ytqfx/Karbonn_Sparkle_V_1783956_Lollipop.zip

and then flash it...dont interrupt the flashing process because it can result in a dead state of your phone.

Comment: Plz brief about process and tools used in flashing.

Comment: Dear ashish ththe above file has everything you need ..your ROM ,guide for flashing , drivers everything ..after that if you want to ask anything i will guide ..you ...

Comment: I try to install **Android USB driver** but unable to install. I follow these step: [https://youtu.be/9nCfN3bdayQ](https://youtu.be/9nCfN3bdayQ). After doing all these steps successfully no new driver shown under the port menu. I m working on Windows 8.1

Comment: Are you plugging the phone with removed battery (if it is removable ) or in download mode....there are some particular ways to plug the phone in pc by which pc detects the android device port ....can u tell me if your device is showi g in the device manager or not

Comment: Install all these drivers ..including VCOM ,CDC from here and let me know if this helps you..............https://gsmusbdriver.com/karbonn-sparkle-v